# Dynamic filtering with Gallery list view in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have found a way to implement a substitute for a tab control in SharePoint Online. In SharePoint On Premise I used Hillbilly Tabs, but I am not allowed to use SPFx at our tenant so I had to look for other solutions.

I use two lists, one list contains the items that used to be visible on the tabs and then I use that list to perform dynamic filtering of the other list.
In the view settings for the first list I unchecked `"Allow individual item checkboxes"`, because in a tab control you only want to select one tab at a time.

This setup works pretty well, but the user experience is of course a bit odd. So I was happy to find the `"Gallery"` list view. I now have the chance to line up the "tabs" horizontally.
But when I switched to Gallery view, the item checkboxes showed up again (even though `"Allow individual item checkboxes"` was still unchecked in the view settings).

And when I click an item in the list, to filter the other list, no filtering is taking place. Instead I am redirected to another place.

This is how the auto-generated code for the gallery list looks like. Is there anything I can change in the JSON to keep the good behavior (with filtering functioning and no checkboxes) of the basic list I had?

```
{
  "height": 45,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "button",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `hideSelection` to `true` like:

```
"hideSelection": true,
```

**Note**:

> Specifies whether the ability to select rows in the view is disabled or not. **false** is the default behavior inside a list view (meaning selection is visible and enabled). **true** means that users will not be able to select list items.

> For list & compact list layout, `hideSelection` only takes effect when there's a `rowFormatter` element specified. If no `rowFormatter` is specified, then `hideSelection` is ignored. For 'Tile' layout, `hideSelection` will only take effect if defined inside `tileProps` properties.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint - hideSelection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting#hideselection)

Comment: Changing hideSelection to true takes care of the selection problem, thanks! Do you know what to change to get back the filtering function? When I click the item it navigates inside itself, instead of filtering the other list. When I removed the "defaultClick action", nothing happens with the other list when I click an item.

Comment: Did you use connected list web parts (I guess so)? I am not sure how you implemented filtering on other list.

Comment: I set up the other list to use "dynamic filtering" by items in first list. The dynamic filtering is working if I do not format the first list. I believe it is the "defaultClick action" I got when adding the formatting that is causing the problem, but I not know how to change it to get the filtering function back.

Comment: If you want dynamic filtering on another list and want to use gallery view on the "filter list", you need to keep ``` "hideSelection": false,``` in the JSON, but you need to remove ```"customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }  ``` from the JSON.

Comment: But it would be really great if the defaultClick could mean the same thing as a selection does...

Comment: buttons with `defaultClick` action will do the same thing as clicking the list item in an uncustomized view. When clicked on list item, it opens the list item & clicking on the file or folder in document library results in the file or folder being opened.

Comment: While `hideSelection` mimics the selection of list item or file using checkbox against the row.

Comment: Yes, but what has been difficult in this scenario, is that the behavior is different depending on if you use a "List" view or "Gallery" view for the filter list for dynamic filtering. In a dynamic filtering scenario you do not want to open items when clicking. This works for "List" view but not for "Gallery" view.